# jquery serialize with email

Tags: jquery, forms, function

I'm using serialize() in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#form").submit(function(){
     var c = $(this).serialize();
     alert(c);
     return false;
     });
     });
    </script>
```

The alert shows my form values ok but for the email, it presents it like this:

somename%40company.com

Is that correct? Will it end up correctly with an @ when I insert it in my database??

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that correct?

Yes, it is correct. It is called URL encoding of parameters. The server will be able to properly decode it. If you want to send the value with AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                // process the results of the AJAX request
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Many thanks, I understood how it works thanks to your example. Thanks again!